# activatedRoute returning empty object

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-activatedroute

I have a routing module that has routes set up for a number of other modules, that I've managed to use `activatedRoute` for with no problems. But I've now created a singular component and it is returning an empty object when I try and use `activatedRoute`.

The routing module looks like something like this:

```js
const routes = [
   {
      path: 'path',
      component: myComponent,
      resolve: { resolver: myCustomResolver },
      children: [
         {
            path: '',
            children: [
               {
                  path: 'users',
                  loadChildren: 'app/users.module#UsersModule'
               },
               {
                  path: 'articles',
                  loadChildren: 'app/articles.module#ArticlesModule'
               }
            ]
         },
         // this is the new component
         { path: 'stories', component: StoriesComponent }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm using the same method for `activatedRoute` in both modules and new component:

```js
export class StoriesComponent implements OnInit {
   private routeData;

   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      // this is returning an empty object '{}'
      this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.routeData = data;
      });
   }
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.subscribe...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to access parent resolve data in the children. Try this.

```
this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data):

> data: Observable<Data> - An observable of the static and resolved data of this route.

In the provided routing configuration there is no static data or [dynamic data resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve). That is why `data` is an empty object.

Comment: My apologies I do in fact have a resolver, I just forgot to add it into the example.